# SQL select all rows with the same ticker where at least one of the rows includes a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql, function, where-clause

I have a database of stock tickers. Each ticker has a "structure" that signifies the type of deal we participated in in order to receive the shares. Examples of structures are Primary Offerings ("PO"), Secondary Offerings ("SEC"), "CMPO", "PIPE", etc. It is possible that the database includes a ticker multiple times with different structure. For example, the ticker "AAPL" could exist 2 times - one time with a structure of "PO" and another time with a structure of "SEC". I am trying to write a query that gathers all of the instances of a ticket if at least one of the structures is "PO". I want to show all of the structures that we have participated in in that ticker.

`select * from @mytable where structure = 'PO'` will only show me the deals with structure PO. If a ticker has a structure equal to 'PO' then I want all deals with that ticker regardless of the structure.

I have also tried:

```
select * from (select distinct ticker from @mytable where structure = 'PO') PO
join @mytable m on PO.ticker = m.ticker
```

This works, but joining a table to the same table seems redundant and it seems like there should be a better way to do this.

I am writing this query in SQL -- could someone please help me write a query for this situation? Thank you!!

Comment: *if at least one of the structures is "PO".*  Try using [EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way around selecting from the table twice. however if you don't like the self join you could do a correlated subquery.

```
select * from mytable where ticker in
 (select ticker from mytable where structure = 'PO')
```